# Load test with 300 simultaneous users using jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

How can i load test a login page with 300 simultaneous users using jmeter (not one user after another. Login with 300 users at the same time)? What should be the thread group setting for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter is perfect for the job! You will need a CSV file with 300 names and passwords. Then you would need to use CSVDataSetConfig: 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
Here is a link to a short tutorial: http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series
Video #4 and #5 describe exactly what you need.

BTW, same functionality is supported by [blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com/), free of charge up to a level of 50 concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) set to 300 users

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking at http://loadimpact.com you can simulate users visiting your website. It is not free though